# further intertwine its canon into a complicated universe which now seems baked into the internet

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm having a hard time understanding this phrase in the following passage:
"further intertwine its canon into a complicated universe which now seems baked into the internet"

> Perhaps the most obvious of the identity categories, conspiracy
> theorists make up a central role in the schizo-posting universe. This
> is where we see the purest expression of anxiety and despair of the
> individual in face of the technological-global-corporate-state.
> Conspiracy theories of course are always common within millenarian
> societies. These stories become a sort of folk hermeneutic to decipher
> what academics might call “Elite Theory”. This collection of political
> folklore combined with ancient myth creates a grand canon of good vs.
> evil. Populated with figures such as Alex Jones, Terry Davis, and John
> McAffee, schizo-posters carry on this tradition through modern
> memetics and **further intertwine its canon into a complicated universe
> which now seems baked into the internet.**
>
> https://legacy.donotresearch.net/posts/millenarian-dreams-of-the-schizo-scene/

While I understand that "its canon" refers to a body of knowledge conspiracy theorists have created, I'm not sure exactly what "a complicated universe" refers to, or to what "which" is connected. I think the overall meaning is that conspiracy theorists are making their knowledge more and more complicated and it has now become deeply ingrained in the online culture, but I'm not really confident in my interpretation.
Could anyone explain this to me? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: It's a really pretentious writing style, hardly suitable for non-native Anglophones (or indeed for anyone who isn't well-educated *and* willing to put the effort in to fully understand such "purple prose").

Comment: ...besides which, I think the whole presentation of that "canon" is internally self-contradictory. The actual canon is blindingly simple (the entire universe is basically just Good vs Evil), but the writer here calls it "complicated", *and* uses complex syntax and vocabulary to "analyze" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase, "a complicated universe" is a common poetic way of referring to the complexity of society, usually in contrast to the past.

The writing is terrible so it's unclear what "which" refers to, but the best candidate semantically is "canon", so it probably was intended to mean:

> schizo-posters ... further intertwine its canon into our complicated society, and the canon now seems baked into the internet.

Comment: It's hard to be definite about what the author intends. It's possible the universe is a purely online one or a wider one that includes offline things. If the former is the case, then both the canon and the wider online universe would have become integral parts of the internet (been "baked into the internet"). But who knows? Possibly not even the author.

Comment: Actually, I think "the canon" is the *only* credible referent for *which now seems baked into the Internet*. In which case this pretentious writer is "hoist by his own petard" - effectively trashing his own argument by writing a containing sentence that's manifestly ungrammatical. The moral of which is *Don't try to use language more complicated than what you know how to use correctly*.